# Using Statsmodels ztest

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I am trying to calculate a one-sided z test, and doing this I am using:

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ztest
```

If for example, I had some distribution against which I want to compare a single sample to determine if they are significantly different, I am doing something like this:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=6

ztest(x,value=6)
```

Is this correct? I am confused by the docs where it says `In the two sample case, the value is the difference between the mean of x1 and mean of x2 under the Null hypothesis.` shown [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ztest.html).

Comment: correct, if x2 is None, then it's just the one sample case with null hypothesis mean of x1 = value (or mean(x1) - value = 0).

Comment: @Josef perfect, thanks for help.